# Get 'python-keyring' to stop prompting for 'encrypted keyring' password

Tags: ubuntu, python, password, mercurial

**Situation:**

I followed these [instructions for setting up the mercurial keyring extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeyringExtension).

On an Ubuntu 12.04.4 (precise) machine, it works perfectly following the instructions. Prompted for a password once, and now I can 'hg pull'/'hg clone' etc without having to enter a username or password.

On an Ubuntu 14.04.1 (trusty) machine, I had to deviate from the instructions slightly to get it to work by specifying installing 'mercurial-keyring' 0.6.0 (following advice found [here](http://fink.9193.n7.nabble.com/Mercurial-keyring-extension-issue-quot-failed-to-import-extension-quot-td43602.html) but did also involve some troubleshooting on my end). This is working, but every time it prompts: "Please enter password for encrypted keyring:", so this is not ideal.

***Question:***

How can I get 'python-keyring' to stop prompting for the encrypted keyring password every time?

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else that encounters this, it is simply because trusty simply no longer allows you to set empty passwords anymore and my keyring password on precise was blank.

I know I read this somewhere but can't seem to find it now.